# PicklingError in Broadcasting: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm creating a function to read values from saved textfile using pyspark & then I want to broadcast that variable. So I wrote following code

```
def retrieveIndex(key):
    name=key+'.txt'
    z=sc.textFile(name)
    #rdd_index=sc.broadcast(z)
    return(z)
z=retrieveIndex('country')
rdd_b=sc.broadcast(z.collect)
rdd_b.value[0]
```

I'm getting following error message after running this code

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

Kindly suggest me what changes I need to do

Comment: You are trying to broadcast the method `z.collect` itself (which is an instance method and it is not picklable), not the collected data, please, change `z.collect` to `z.collect()`, so that you broadcast the collected data.

Comment: Thanks a lot mkaran.It's working

Comment: I'm glad it helped! :)